# Compare two numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

https://i.stack.imgur.com/71w9v.png

I have to find how much money a player wins.

This must be done by creating a function called digits `Int->Int->Int`. For example if the first input is `13758455` and the second input of the function is `13758455` then I should get `1000000` in the compiler.

This is normally an easy task in Java but I wasn't able to find something like a counter to count up as I find more digits in a number.

Comment: Can you give some more examples? What does the task description mean by 'getting digits' right. In '123456789' and '123465888', do you have four digits right (because the both start with the same four numbers) or six (because 1,2,3,4 and 8 are at the correct position) or even seven (because 1,2,3,4,5,6,8 appear in both numbers)?

Comment: in this instance you get 1,2,3,4 and 8 right because they are in the same position in both numbers so you have found 5 digits right out of 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no state in Haskell, you cannot have counters like you would in imperative languages.

You will often use recursion for this matter. Here is an example:

```
module Main where

moneyWon :: Int -> Int
moneyWon 8 = 1000000
moneyWon 7 = 100000
moneyWon 6 = 8000
moneyWon 5 = 300
moneyWon 4 = 20
moneyWon 3 = 5
moneyWon 2 = 1
moneyWon _ = 0

digits :: Int -> Int -> Int
digits 0 0 = 0
digits x y = digits dx dy + if mx == my then 1 else 0
    where (dx, mx) = divMod x 10
          (dy, my) = divMod y 10

main = do
    print $ (moneyWon . digits 12345678) 12345668
```

Notes:

- counting corresponding digits and evaluating the prize are two different concerns, that's why I've separated them
- the `divMod x 10` is a way to get the lowest meaning digit in base 10
- in real life, you should not use an integer to hold the digits since it is more a list matter than a number matter (that's why the number starts at 10000000 and not at 0, forcing the user to enter the right number of digits).
- Using `Int` leaves with the task to check the number is valid.